# March form and instrumentation

Tags: musical-forms, instrumentation, march, wind-band

I'm currently composing a Sousa-style march for concert band. I've made it through the intro and the first strain, but I only have a vague idea of where to go from there. I've played bassoon on several marches like Sousa's Stars and Stripes Forever, Liberty Bell March, Hands Across the Sea, and the Invincible Eagle, as well as a couple others by different composers, so I have a bit of knowledge as far as general march form. This is my idea of how it's supposed to go:

- intro (4 or 8 bars)
- first strain (16 bars repeated)
- second strain (16 bars repeated)
- trio (32 bars)
- break strain (16-32 bars)
- trio (16-32 bars, repeats with break strain)
  If I'm wrong about something or if you have any tips, could you let me know?

What has been a bigger challenge for me, however, is instrumentation. I dabble in a number of instruments (and don't worry, I'm familiar with all things percussion!) but I haven't played a march on any wind instrument except bassoon, so I don't have a great idea on how to write the different parts. What I did for the first strain:

- piccolo, flutes 1 & 2, oboe 1, clarinet 1, trumpets 1 & 2, and glockenspiel on melody
- oboe 2, clarinets 2 & 3, trumpet 3 on supporting harmony
- bassoons 1 & 2, horns 1, 2, 3, & 4 on offbeats
- trombones 1 & 2, euphonium on harmony (same notes as bassoons and horns but on the downbeats)
- bass clarinet, baritone sax, bass trombone/trombone 3, tuba, string bass on bass line
- alto clarinet, alto sax 1 & 2, tenor sax doing their own thing! (It's a fun counterpoint of sorts to the main melody)

I appreciate all tips and criticisms that will help improve my march. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Guest W. Questions soliciting opinions aren't a fit for the main site here, but after your reputation grows by a few votes, this would be perfect for The Auditorium, our chat room devoted to discussion of compositions and composing. Please consider browsing the site; perhaps there are questions for which you could provide helpful answers, which is one way to build your in-site reputation.

Comment: I suggest studying the scores of other marches to better understand the genre.

Comment: With the described strict off-beat assignments some people of the concert band may not be inclined to play a further composition from you.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compose a Sousa-style march, complete with proper instrumentation, you're best off studying Sousa's marches. Luckily, Sousa's works have fallen into the public domain, and a lot of his marches have made it into [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:Sousa,_John_Philip), complete with instrumentation.

Beware: Sousa was the most fond of marches structured either like this (e.g. *The Stars and Stripes Forever*):

Intro - 1st Strain - 2nd Strain - Trio - Breakstrain - Trio - Breakstrain - Trio

...or like this (all non-intro strains are 16 bars and repeated) (e.g. *Manhattan Beach*):

Intro - 1st Strain - 2nd Strain - 1st Trio Strain - 2nd Trio Strain